# Show popular feature requests in tab even if they are status-declined

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bountied-tab

Feature requests seem to get removed from the Meta [Feature requests tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=requests) if they are `status-declined` even if their vote count would make them eligible to be shown. For example, that leads to my recent [social networking proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106717/does-so-need-social-networking-features-to-improve-the-experience-for-expert-use) being excluded.

Is that fair?

Of course it's the team's prerogative to decline requests. It's also perfectly fine to dislike the proposal - that is not the issue here.

But it's a *popular feature request*, and hence my feeling is it belongs on the list of popular feature requests. It has happened that minds changed and declined requests were eventually implemented. Popular declined requests can also spawn other requests that have a chance of being received more graciously.

Comment: +1 that should *at least* help avoid duplicates of those popular decline requests.

Answer (score 3):

The "reqs" tab always seemed like a "todo" (or "to-process") list to me and in that sense it makes sense not to show completed or rejected requests. Including rejected feature requests would clutter the page with more than half being declined.

I was thinking we could add it as an option, but we can already achieve the same effect.

[If you want to see all the highest voted feature requests regardless of status, you could search by tag and sort by votes:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[feature-request]%20closed%3a0)

```
[feature-request] closed:0
```

[Or if you still want to ignore the completed requests:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[feature-request]%20-[status-completed]%20closed%3a0)

```
[feature-request] -[status-completed] closed:0
```

Comment: That's a fair point. I didn't realize there were so many declined suggestions