# Why doesn't Stack Overflow have Twitter?

Tags: discussion, twitter

Even [Martial Arts](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/) has Twitter, and they only get 1 question in 3 days.

This is curious. What prevents SO and MSO from Tweeting?

Comment: What exactly would you have them to tweet about?

Comment: @Lix The same thing as all the other SE sites, that is, interesting questions and answers.

Comment: Stack Overflow currently gets 5.8k questions _per day_. I don't really think a dedicated twitter account for Stack Overflow would be helpful to anyone. What's there to advertise, _everyone_ knows Stack Overflow.

Comment: @YannisRizos But why not? Almost all the other SE sites do. What's special about SO?

Comment: There are already several tag-related SO Twitter feeds...let's just say I wouldn't subscribe to any of them. Largely useless IMHO.

Comment: @KendallFrey it will generate too much tweets to be really interesting ...

Comment: I've already told you what's special about SO: 5.8k questions per day. In comparison, the next SE site by questions per day is Mathematics with 280 questions.

Comment: Isn't there some sort of bot for finding and tweeting interesting questions? It's not like there's a rule that it needs to tweet EVERY popular question. Just a few a day.

Comment: Someone has the @stackoverflow handle and they were never able to procure it, IIRC

Comment: @BenBrocka stackoverflow isn't the only possibility. For example, Super User's handle is StackSuper_User.

Comment: @Lix: Downtime would be an appropriate topic

Comment: `#jquery` `#unicorns`  `#waffles`

Comment: @OliverSalzburg https://twitter.com/stackstatus

Comment: @YannisRizos: Oh that's so last hours news!

Comment: Stack Exchange has a [Google+ page](http://plus.google.com/+StackExchange/posts).  Blog items such as the Data Visualization Contest might gain additional visibility.

Comment: FYI, the all-SE-sites Twitterbot, @[StackExchange](https://twitter.com/stackexchange), includes SO posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ideas actually aren't that misplaced. Don't get me wrong, Stack Overflow doesn't need its own Twitter account. In fact, I'd almost venture to say that none of the sites really need their own Twitter accounts. However, having a *human* Tweeting questions is a good thing that will benefit the community a lot more than a bot will.

Why? Because it's a bot. How many automated Twitter bots would you say you follow?  How many are you excited to receive spam from?  The fact is, bots just aren't that exciting. Maybe their owners are excited about them, but the actual general population probably is uninterested.

However, if you're a great programmer and have a lot of programmer friends who follow you on Twitter, then when you find and share interesting questions, chances are that will set off your Twitter friends' radar, and chances are they may decide to see what you find interesting.  You're a person. People are interesting. Bots are not.

So, in short, we have millions of users who could possibly be Tweeting questions, and this scales much better than a bot. Hope this helps!

Comment: If you liked "People are interesting. Bots are not." you may also enjoy [Does SO need social networking features to improve the experience for expert users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106717/does-so-need-social-networking-features-to-improve-the-experience-for-expert-use)

Comment: Sorry @PopularDemand, I'm actually against adding social networking features on Stack Exchange itself. Let Twitter and Facebook handle that stuff as it's what they do. People do better at what they specialize in, and the same goes for businesses. ;) Thanks for the link though.