# Allow high-rep users to recommend posts for and against tweeting

Tags: feature-request, twitter

I would like for high rep users to be able to recommend posts for tweeting through the site's twitter account.  Call this a "positive recommendation" if you will.

I would also like for high rep users to "flag" a question to *prevent* it from being tweeted.  And we could call this a "negative recommendation."

***Why?***
[This question on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223634/53019) led to some follow up commentary within [The Whiteboard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard).  The question itself is a "meh" question that could have been tolerated, but then it got way too much publicity from being tweeted.  The problem is that this isn't an exception.  This pattern has repeated itself before, and this request is to help control the damage meh questions do to a site's reputation when they get a lot of visibility.

#### How it might work...

What I'm envisioning is two more icons within the share panel.
[image]

1. The first would recommend the question for tweeting.
2. The second would count as a recommendation against tweeting the question.

If there aren't any positive recommendations, then the [existing tweet selection algorithm] would apply but including a check to skip questions with recommendations against them.

Once a positively recommended question is tweeted, it would be removed from further tweet consideration.  Just like it is handled currently.

#### Benefits...

- Improve quality of what is tweeted - active communities can curate for the best and make sure it gets highlighted.
- Make selection more human and less automated (therefore more valuable or less spam like).  Higher quality tweets may lead to higher numbers of followers.

---

**Footnotes:**

This wouldn't apply to SO or MSO as [they don't have twitter accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155113/194162).

My request is related to this [MSO request to allow moderators to retweet with the site account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106064/194162) but is different in that a) high rep users could participate and b) only recommendations would be made and users would not directly send the tweet.

Comment: We already have buttons for users to provide feedback on whether or not they feel a post is of high or low quality; it's up/down votes.

Comment: @Servy it's known for ages that one of these buttons (vote down) [doesn't work in hot questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164078/165773 "'There are just too many new visitors to keep things under local community control, and there are just too many new voters and commenters to get things going as designed'")

Comment: @Servy - this is a bit different.  The questions are merely meh but not close worthy.  And they could be tolerated, but you certainly don't want to advertise them for the site.  The problem is that they'll gather up votes from the "popular / fun questions are **great**" camp.

Comment: @GlenH7 It sounds like such a question should still be downvoted then.  And if the problem is nobody is doing that, then do you really think the people upvoting these questions are going to actively suggest they not be tweeted?  These seem like the kinds of questions that, if people are going out of their way to upvote, that they'll go out of their way to tweet/suggest tweeting.

Comment: Having the questions hit the hot questions and tweet drastically increases the number of people who *want* to see it and upvote it on "interesting" criteria rather than the "useful" criteria.  People who see it on the hot network and go "meh" to the question rarely visit the question, and those that do don't always have the rep to downvote if they were so inclined.

Comment: @MichaelT So you think those same people who upvote are going to not suggest tweeting, and those who don't have the rep and/or interest to downvote are going to go out of their way to suggest that it not be tweeted?

Comment: @Servy people who can and do downvote in an attempt to limit the hotness formula impacts are often hopelessly unable to have an effect once a question reaches a certain critical rep.  Then it gets tweeted and the floodgates open and you get 5k views on a question in a day where the normal views on a question are ~500... and the rep explodes. Unless a mod is active enough to protect (10k can't protect within a time period) and put notices on it often gets a dozen of meh answers that ultimately leads to a poor impression for new visitors about the site's quality and experience.

Comment: @Servy per my reading, _protect_ feature is proposed for "high rep users" - not to _those who don't have the rep..._

Comment: @MichaelT Yes, I'm not disputing that, I never was, I'm saying that this change wouldn't change that.  It would be just as bad with this feature as without it in the situations you've described.

Comment: What this is asking is the ability to put on delay the tweet, let things that *shouldn't* get tweeted from getting tweeted, and allow the site to prepare (protecting the question, notices, deleting existing poor answers to avoid setting a poor example for others). Significant focused viewership can do significant damage to the site (mod flags, meta posts, "why did my answer get deleted", etc...).  This is further increased when the mod count is lower on the site... (and we haven't been able to persuade Yannis to carry a pager hooked up to the twitter feed yet.)

Comment: @MichaelT The fact remains that if people are going out of their way to upvote questions like this, and they're not being downvoted, then what makes you think there are going to be dramatically more votes to not tweet than votes to tweet?

Comment: @Servy if this was something that was limited to people of a sufficiently high rep, one *tends* to be under the impression that they have a better idea of the site and how they want it presented to the populous at large.  At worse, its no worse than it currently is.  At best, we can work to avoid [the belief that the twitter feed should be hooked to the close queue](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6372/40980) by presenting quality questions rather than popular meh questions.

Comment: @MichaelT So then just change the tweeting algorithm to only incorporate votes from high rep users, rather than presenting new buttons that are intended to be used identically to the voting buttons.

Comment: @Servy That would be a happily accepted alternative, but due to the hotness formula algorithm improvements that have been suggested multiple times being rejected, this is an attempt to improve something *without* requesting the algorithm change as the sounds from SE are that the technicals of how the algorithms work makes changing them extremely onerous.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa And you think this is a *less* complex alternative?  It's adding a ton more UI work and making the algorithm quite a bit *more* complex.  How could it possibly be *easier* to implement?

Comment: @Servy I don't propose to know the technicals on the SE side of what is easier or harder. If someone from SE comes in and says this is far more onerous and not technically feasible, that is a completely sufficient response. It's worth asking though to see if it *is* possible because it would be a good benefit to people being able to advertise their sites more effectively.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa If it's completely impossible to change how up/downvotes are weighted why would it be easy to add an entirely new metric, with it's own weights, into the algorithm?  You're claiming that no changes at all are realistic...except for this one?

Comment: @Servy **"Providing a manual lever where trusted members of the community can endorse high-quality questions actually sounds like a good idea in principle"** ([Robert Harvey](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215684/allow-high-rep-users-to-recommend-posts-for-tweeting/215690?noredirect=1#comment697079_215690))

Comment: @gnat Okay.  I'm not opposed to it either; I'm just saying that *we're already getting that information through votes*, we simply need to use it.  Getting the exact same information through a different button is just wasting people's time.

Comment: @Servy information from votes is **not the same**, not even close. In hot questions, you get tens if not hundreds upvotes from careless passers by (aka "lemmings"), this completely obscures whatever votes could be there from "high rep users" (10-15-20Kers if I correctly understand this request). The point seems to be to "amplify" feedback of active site users which is currently lost in the noise

Comment: @gnat You seem to have not been reading [my comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215684/allow-high-rep-users-to-recommend-posts-for-tweeting?noredirect=1#comment697053_215684).  If you want to only look at high rep users then only look at high rep users, that's fine, but look at their votes, not an entirely separate button which they'll enter the exact same thing as their vote.

Comment: @Servy you mean, voting buttons for these users could work as recommend / suspend tweeting? Functionally the same request, but instead of "two more icons", have up/down buttons be "overloaded" to additionally submit the tweeting feedback when clicked by hi-repz?

Comment: @gnat I mean that the algorithm, instead of using some extra data field, can simply filter out votes from users without sufficient rep when determining what should be used.  The information is all there; votes are only anonymized when displayed.  It doesn't change how you vote, it's simply changing the algorithm to leverage the information already provided, namely the score *of users above a given rep*.

Comment: @Servy I see. That's an interesting alternative, but it may break at the opposite side of the issue I'm afraid. At sites / tags with small count of high rep users, this info won't make a reliable feed. Imagine like only 3-5 high rep users are online, they simply won't make stable representative "stream of data" for the feed

Comment: @Servy in case you're unfamiliar with the background, you may like to have a quick look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192046/in-network-hot-questions-formula-discard-answers-when-voting-evidence-indicat) which details more about the algo and has the official SE response; the precise technical problem they complained about was looking individually at the votes on questions/answers as opposed to aggregates. The high-rank-suggestion could be an aggregate perhaps making it feasible, I don't know, either way it might be good background for you to read.

Comment: @gnat And how would that problem be solved by adding new buttons?  You still don't have enough information in those cases either way.

Comment: @Servy my understanding is, it's supposed to "complement" what works now. Fine-tune it so to speak, as opposed to completely replacing it

Comment: @gnat And I'm saying that wherever you would otherwise use these new buttons, you can just use whatever those users used as their votes instead.  It'll be the exact same information, it just involves zero UI changes instead of adding a whole new UI interaction to get information we already have.  I fail to see why this is so complicated.  The proposal is asking to collect information we already have.  There's simply no reason to do that.

Comment: @Servy I see, thanks. That way looks worth considering. Overloading existing buttons to provide additional fine-tune "data stream", as a means to add the same functionality as requested but avoid UI complication, sounds neat

Comment: @gnat It's not really overloading the buttons.  The buttons simply provide votes.  Those votes are used in all sorts of places for all sorts of things, ranging from rep changes, to post bans, to search results, to interesting questions, to readers, etc..  Lots of places use the votes on a post to do...something.  This would be yet another "thing" consuming vote information.  It's not changing the meaning of a vote; a vote still simply indicates helpfulness/usefulness.

Comment: @Servy with all due respect, I prefer to stick with "overloading" term - simply because I am not aware of any other use cases when up/down voting data was ever "filtered by rep" for whatever purposes. By the way, maybe this is because of concerns about keeping voting anonymous - if this is the case, "additional icons" approach could actually turn out a path of smaller resistance. Voting anonymity is a delicate matter

Comment: @gnat Given that you wouldn't ever see the numeric value for this algorithm, it would likely be on questions with a fair number of votes already (thus providing a lot of data to mask the votes) etc. I can't see it being an issue.

Comment: @Servy that sounds reasonable to me. The question is, would it also sound reasonable to everyone at SE team? If yes, great, this way indeed looks more elegant to me. But if not... if someone raises and sticks to concern about voting anonymity... consider it buried

Comment: @Servy - I think you have a solid suggestion in filtering the high-rep users' votes to adjust the tweeting algorithm.  Would you mind capturing those comments as an alternative answer?  If you don't want to do so, would you mind if I put them into an answer?  I think it would answer the intent of the question quite well along with some additional benefits such as keeping the UI simplified.

Comment: @GlenH7 You're free to write up an answer if you want, I'm not sufficiently interested to write a detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

#### An alternative approach...<sup>1</sup>

***Short version***

> just change the tweeting algorithm to only incorporate votes from high rep users

***Long version***

The proposed approach has at least a few problems with it:

1. Not everyone who can use it will use it because it requires additional steps outside of normal site usage.
2. It requires additional UI work to implement.
3. StackExchange already has a better reflection of the high-rep user community's thoughts on questions through up | down votes.

The alternative approach would simply filter out votes from users without sufficient rep when determining what should be used for the tweeing algorithm.

Advantages:

- The information is already there and this approach avoids creating another data field.
- The scoring mechanism is already in place.
- It doesn't change how you vote, it's simply changing the algorithm to leverage the information already provided, namely the score from users above a given rep.

Voting anonymity would still be preserved - the filtered value would never be displayed.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This answer was originally proposed by [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186381/servy) in the comments to this question.  With Servy's permission, I wrote the answer up as I thought it was worthwhile and it would be an alternative approach to meeting the spirit of the request.  Please see [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215684/allow-high-rep-users-to-recommend-posts-for-and-against-tweeting#comment697188_215684) and [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215684/allow-high-rep-users-to-recommend-posts-for-and-against-tweeting#comment697163_215684)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Given the community's record with bikeshed votes, I think recommending questions for tweeting is going to have an adverse effect on the site overall.

Every question that is tweeted will get views and votes out of proportion to the actual quality of the answer.  I can see how this could be gamed to give a question attention it doesn't really deserve.

All in all, not an idea I would endorse.

Comment: recommend/protect feature is proposed for "high rep users" (10/15/20Kers?) - do you expect _these_ guys ride on promoting bikeshed stuff?

Comment: @gnat [Yes.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/publicist?userid=25936) ;)

Comment: @Yannis content of the link you refer says "No" to me :)

Comment: @gnat: No, but all the lemmings that visit the site from the tweet will vote on the post, without regard for the votes that are already there.  It's the same thing as Redditting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey as far as I can tell, additional links aren't expected to be displayed to low-rep passers by ("lemmings")

Comment: @gnat: Then why would you bother tweeting?

Comment: for the [same reasons as Yannis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215684/allow-high-rep-users-to-recommend-posts-for-tweeting/215685#comment697046_215690), why else. If we're talking about 15Kers, it could go especially easy - 1. protect the question 2. tweet 3. profit

Comment: @Yannis FWIW, you've only got two closed questions out of 25.  I suspect this is a better ratio than the tweet bot.  (Alternate suggestion: give Yannis the twitter feed? ... but then, this is kind of what is being suggested)

Comment: @gnat: I think I might be in favor of letting people tweet questions if we could also remove the hot list tweeting in exchange.

Comment: well, that "would be a happily accepted alternative" ([Jimmy Hoffa](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215684/allow-high-rep-users-to-recommend-posts-for-tweeting/215690?noredirect=1#comment697054_215684))

Comment: Actually I'm probably not articulating myself properly.  Providing a manual lever where trusted members of the community can endorse high-quality questions actually sounds like a good idea in principle, but I can't think clearly due to my revulsion for Twitter.

Answer (score -2):

> but then it got way too much publicity from being tweeted.

I'm extremely skeptical StackExchange is going to implement policies specifically meant to *discourage* people visiting SE sites.

It's *good* if people visit questions. If it's low quality, downvote, close, do whatever.

Secondly, this is silly manual work that is redundant with downvoting and closing questions. If an answer receives many downvotes, it goes to the bottom of the page, is displayed in lighter grey, the user many delete the answer, etc. If *anything* I would automate from that, but if someone wants to tweet, even, "Hey look at this silly wrong answer," that's their right and discretion.

Comment: This is more to help control the "damage" from questions that are meh, but not necessarily close worthy.

Comment: @GlenH7 if it's not closeworthy it's not doing any damage. And people visiting the site is certainly not damage.

Comment: question asked has nothing to do with close votes [Twitter bots don't share posts with closevotes on them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139857/165773)

Comment: _"if it's not closeworthy it's not doing any damage"_ -- [study I did about a year ago](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5413/31260 "Answers quality in hot questions") suggests that this assumption is flawed

Comment: @gnat that's not damage. new users is good. even if new users' first answers are bad.

Comment: This isn't about discouraging people from visiting the site; it's about stopping the site being advertised as something it's not.

Comment: **'my favorite pattern is from MetaFilter, which is: When we start seeing effects of scale, we shut off the new user page. "Someone mentions us in the press and how great we are? Bye!" That's a way of raising the bar, that's creating a threshold of participation. And anyone who bookmarks that page and says "You know, I really want to be in there; maybe I'll go back later," that's the kind of user MeFi wants to have.'** ([A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy](http://www.shirky.com/writings/group_enemy.html))

Comment: How would this feature discourage readership? The way I see it, if the quality of the posts that are tweeted goes up, that will increase engagement from people with the twitter account- **and by proxy** increase engagement with the sites that get tweeted. Imagine if more of what the twitter account spits out are posts that are of a sincerely high quality, that will attract people who have interest in that content and are more likely going to generate similarly high quality content. There's no way this could be bad *other than possibly the technical implementation which I know nothing about*

Comment: Also in your answer here you're missing one fact in your thoughts about just downvoting fixes this - it doesn't. Getting downvotes respected by the hotness algorithm has been requested but rejected, as it stands they hardly have any effect on the ranking of a question that gets *many* low/no-quality/me-too answers. If simply down voting balanced against the algorithmic ranking of these posts then this feature wouldn't be requested because the automated tweets would likely choose quality content. This feature speaks about giving a manual lever to allow choosing quality content as well.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa there's no problem. Visitors are good. You've supplied exactly one opinion that visitors are bad, and zero evidence. For instance, visitors see ads. Some become users. I don't know where this idea that we don't want the cruft of human beings who look at bad questions or answers and continue their existence thinking SE is full of such answers and questions has gained traction, but apparently you and gnat are really into it.

Comment: When did I say visitors are bad? I said if we increase the quality of our twitter feed we'll get more visitors. Where in that opinion is "visitors are bad" ?

Comment: @JimmyHoffa are you claiming that a proper subset of current SO tweets will lead to more visitors?

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I see...  take some effort to curate tweets we think will attract more people so it's easier to follow SO tweets. I'm still against this and don't think it will work this way but admit it's more subtle. For one I think it's perfectly fine that ridiculously bad questions and answers grab visitors. I think probably half of my own visits to SO are to look at stupid questions someone linked me.

Comment: @djechlin the difficulty is that no other site is SO.  No other site has the number of active moderators to protect questions quickly, 20k+ users to delete bad answers, and the shear volume of other posts to cover up some of the damage on the front page.  On smaller sites, we may be lucky if there's a mod on at that time, or a 20k+ user (much less three) and the front page moves at a glacial pace compared to SO.  What works for SO doesn't necessarily work for the other, smaller sites.

Comment: [analysis in this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773 "'you can't overlook the fact that it only started growing when it became a --vigorously moderated-- serious Q&A site'") suggests that _stable increase in visits_ happens only when site strongly focuses on providing _high quality content_