# Errors in Edit description

Tags: discussion, edits, profanity

I made a small edit (please the merits of the edit are not what is in issue here), and made a typo in the edit reason.

Please see 
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17620086/revisions)

Now, instead of saying **popped**, you can see what I wrote. In cases where an error is made in the edit description, what should one do?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. Tpyos happen.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins what if I was saying "tucked end brace into code format" and got that wrong?!?

Comment: I still don't think it would matter. The text isn't readily visible to the majority of the site's users, and the ones that view edits are probably already aware that typos and other mistakes are just part of the process. Perhaps a helpful way to avoid such mistakes is to avoid non-specific words such as "popped" and "tucked" in favor of an easily-repeatable phrase that becomes muscle memory from regular use: "Improved code formatting," etc.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins that's a good idea. When I realised what I DID actually write, I must admit, it sounds funny..., but then it is 3am here.. Who CAN see the edit summaries?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins hahahha just saw your joke... I am slooow too..night./..mooorning...

Comment: Everyone can see edit summaries *if they look*, but they're a bit out of the way. FWIW, it is possible to remove them in *extreme* scenarios, but... We're talking "pasted the company password into the summary field" kinds of bad.

Comment: @Shog9 FWIW???? and yes I'm an aussie and we are pretty renown for our "colorful" language, it mean avoiding a ling list of words to avoid possible slips... should a provide a list of innocuous words that should be avoided?

Comment: Eh, I wouldn't worry about it - folks put [all sorts of strange things](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/186681/4) into those edit summaries. FWIW = For What It's Worth.

Comment: @Shog9 hm will go look, Meta becomes my bedtime reading. I brwose the posts for fun before I go to bed !! How sad is my life ;) ps FYI I sent you an email FWIW, IDK we r developing a new language of abbrev IMO, g2g bbl bfn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you notice it within 5 minutes of making the edit and before anyone else edits the post, you can edit the question again (making some further change to it), fix the mistake in the edit summary, and it will all be compiled into one edit (your typo will disappear, as if it never happened).

If you notice it after that, nothing can really be done, but it's not really a big deal. People don't usually pay attention to those anyway, and it's obviously a typo. I wouldn't worry about it :)

Comment: Note that in order for your edit reason to be updated, you have to change something *in the actual post* so the edit doesn't get discarded as being the exact same as the previous edit.

Comment: @animuson maybe that should be put into this or another answer, Wendi, hm, didn't know that, good to know

Comment: @Yve, I've suggest-edited it into this answer; let's see if it goes through.

Comment: @Shog9, your edit summary is hilarious!! well played hahhahahah makes me feel better.. it's cos I come onto these sites in the wee hours of the morning when I cannot sleep.. when I start making mistakes, I know it's time to just browse and keep my fingers still