# Is it possible to tag users?

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page

It could be interesting to tag users, for example by company or profession.

We could check if Ericsson employees contribute more than Nokia employees for example; have companies compete with each other.

Or if Full Stack developers contribute more per person than Front End Developers.

Comment: Ahh.. That reminds me when one time I've answered a question on SO and got a reply from the OP that answers from Israelis are not welcome....

Comment: So I get minus points for posting a question which is said to be a duplicate of another question which has since been removed. Surely my question is now no longer a duplicate? :-)

Answer (score 9):

The focus of Stack Exchange is on its Questions and Answers.

Who they come from should be irrelevant.

Comment: Your answer does not make sense. A big strength of SO is how it treats people; the gamification of Q&A. Adding a company tag to a user might further encourage people to collect even more points.

Comment: @RogerCSWernersson people don't collect points, posts do. I think [this  post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106717/does-so-need-social-networking-features-to-improve-the-experience-for-expert-use) is similar to what you ask. It is also status-declined.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve some information you requesting from the profile of the user. If you use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) you can retrieve some of the metrics you are asking.

If you want to search for a company name, you could try [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/203943/find-people-from-a-company) for example that searches the About Me for a company name.

Since the Q/A sets are more important than the user asking or answering, you will not find very much structured data on the person (on SEDE, or on the user pages themselves), such as the job of the person. You might find the [Stack Overflow Survey](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2015-the-results/) useful if you want to see some statistics on the users that did participate.