# Is it allowed to use Stack Exchange to connect to People?

Tags: discussion, jobs, project

Is it allowed to use Stack Exchange to find people who would like to work on a project?

I am basically looking for students who are interested in creating something to show to future employers.

Comment: Downvotes on Meta usually mean that people disagree with what you're asking. In this case, the answer to your question is an astounding ***No***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does SO need social networking features to improve the experience for expert users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151756/282094)

Comment: @rob Actually not really. In the first paraghraph jmort253 explains why he thinks it is a bad idea, but i feel like this paragraph is based on a misunderstanding of the original Question.

Comment: The second paragraph is a joke to me, Considering Chat (which is not traceable in the long run) as a serious tool for collaboration on Questions which have interdisciplinary relevance and require feedback of multiple Subject Matter Experts is the worst idea i have ever heard.

Comment: To be clear, i am really talking about questions which can not be answered by a single field of science. But if Stack Exchange is not interested in being a good tool for interdisciplinary collaboration, it only convices me that the tool i was talking about in the initial Version of this question is desperately needed.

Comment: Kevin, three others also voted to close, you replied to an automatically generated comment; someone's name must be attached to it, mine was chosen. --- In any event, if you feel that your question was not understood or that it's not properly answered you are welcome to edit it and seek reopening. Clairify the difference between your question and **all** potential (not just those two) duplicates. -- If you can format your idea in a manner suitable to how Stack Exchange works you can [propose a new site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/282094), though even A51's existence is under review.

Comment: You can licence (rent) your own instance of an SE site (they call it their "Teams" product) and use it however you like. That would be for your own users though, not the public community here.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it allowed to use Stack Exchange to find non-paid Experts?

No.

> I need a Tool to manage Projects (like this one) in a completely traceable fashion.

I too was interested in that at one time.

You say "No Tool currently available completely satisfies my needs", but there are many such applications already, see e.g. https://www.capterra.com/requirements-management-software/

Comment: Thank you very much for link. I did not know about capterra, need to save that link.
Will check if there are some new tools which might fit my needs.

Comment: You're welcome. Call me a nerd but I think the topic is a bit interesting, I tried it once myself. I don't think it's commercially viable now, though, because there are so many already. Project Management has moved on a bit too (towards "Agile" instead of "Documentation"). I doubt you need more than one full-time (competent/senior) developer to make an interesting prototype. I see no reason why a developer would want to work with you (personally) though. And "Links back to Stack Exchange for Expert Consultations" sounds a bit off-topic for SE. Maybe you're looking for students.

Comment: Yes, i am basically looking for students (people interested in trying out their new skills, learn something new)
The value i would like to provide them is that everything they do gets well documented, so they can use it as an example of their work for future employees.

Comment: A school might be a better place to look; I think that anyone's asking (trying to recruit) on SE would be considered off-topic and spam. There's also a https://pm.stackexchange.com/ by the way.

Comment: I have actually thought about going to my local university. But SE has a far bigger reach. And all people who use SE Subsites are already interested in the Topic of this Subsite.
I know about pm, this site would be my first shot when trying to look for someone who would be interested in trying himself out.

Comment: For your "Agile instead of Documentation", the Tool i imagine will be able to consolidate the best of both worlds.
You will be able to create Documentation out of it, but still develop the project in a agile fashion.

Comment: I wonder if there's any existing open source PM application you could contribute to -- to make use of the software, to add to it it to suit your needs, and to connect with the people who have already been interested in working with that.

Comment: I will certainly check that, If there is already something which i consider relatively close to my vision, i will start using this and just provide them with feedback on how i feel it can be improved. Currently going through your Capterra link.

Comment: I don't know whether "my" capterra link is all-inclusive, only that it lists many. It may be worth your searching Google or GitHub or something like that too, though perhaps you have already.

Comment: Actually i got the Task from my Manager to check if i can find a way/tool which solves the issues i currently face at my Job. So i spent a high amount of time during the week only searching for a tool/solution but found noting. Have found some of the Tools in capterra, but not all. So i need to go through them.
In the end, my company is big enough to just develop it by ourselve or convince Microsoft to do it. Just tought it would be fun for Students to learn on. Will just pay someone to create a prototype and give it to our Dev Team.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it allowed to use Stack Exchange to find non-paid Experts who work on the project solely out of passion and their love for knowledge?

It is offtopic on any existing SE site (see https://stackexchange.com/sites)

And it goes against how SE sites work.

And trying to find unpaid people, working on solving your problem, that is uninteresting to them is going to fail. And in field of programming there is plenty of paid or interesting or paid and interesting projects.

If you want

> Tool to manage Projects (like this one) in a completely traceable fashion.

you will likely need to pay someone to do that, if all existing ones are somehow insufficient.

You can try to recruit people, but do it outside SE and in places where you can expect volunteers, with more time than ideas (an university project?).

Comment: "uninteresting to them"
That's why i am going to split it in different Key areas. I am certain that someone studying Project Management itself might be looking for some Project to Mange so he can try out his newly occupied skills.
Or someone who is Studying Web Development, would like to try out his skills in Web Dev.

Comment: There is even intrinsic Value in it for them. They can use their part of the project to shown potential emloyers their work.

Comment: Feedback:
I have downvoted your answer because it reads offensive to me. For me it feels like you have only picked out one negative thing (non-paid) in the original Question and based your answer on an emotional reaction that everything someone does should be paid. That's not correct. Everything someone does should have a value in it for himself, be it money or something else.

Comment: I explicitly mentioned "interesting" in my answer :) But if you think that people will be interested in unpaid work on yet another tool to manage projects, just because you dislike all existing ones... I am now going back to work on my private, interesting project exploring something new to me. That is not an unpaid work for someone else :)

Comment: There are 7.5 Billion People in the world. Adoption rate of the internet and SE is rising. It is highly likely that some of those people are interested in my vision and help me achieve it.