# Sort questions by user reputation

Tags: feature-request

I would find it very interesting if I was able to sort the questions by user rep. I find that the most interesting questions are asked by people with high reputation.

Update:
What I meant is to sort them by the reputation of the person that asked them.

Comment: For research purposes, there is always the data dump.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be an unfair option to all the other users on the site. There are a lot of smart users with low reputation.

And a lot of good questions are asked by low rep users.

By just having the option gives off the impression that there is a correlation between high rep and good questions. And I don't think that is something that SO wants.

Comment: You are not forced to use it by default. There are a lot of smart questions with a low score... life is not fair.

Comment: Life isn't fair, but SO can try to be.

Comment: So it's ok to use votes for the questions, but unfair to use the votes for the person that asked the question?

Comment: You lost me       .

Comment: @ionut: The votes are made for the questions, not for the questioner!

Comment: Go to the stackoverflow/newest questions and scroll down. Stop at every question asked by a person with high rep. You will see that most of them are interesting. Also most of them are very specific which is why (I think) they have few votes (there are of course exceptions). I am not trying to say that new/low rep users cannot ask good questions, but I would like to have the option to sort/filter them by minimum rep.

Comment: Oh, well... it seems that I am the only one who sees things different. So, you win this one :P

Comment: Sadly I never even realized this was a competition.

Comment: It was a debate. By the votes that his answer received I understood that the majority of the viewers agreed with his opinion, not mine. Why do you believe that by the simple fact that we don't agree on something we are in a competition?