# Favourite Users

Tags: feature-request, users

Is there a way to tag favourite users?

If not it will be a good idea. I work with a bunch of guys developing stuff, and it would be nice to track their questions or profile because most of their problems are my problems. And having some sort of team SO would be nice. P.S. at the moment we send each other emails with links.

Comment: probable dupe - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stackoverflow-would-be-nice

Comment: why the -1... it was a freaking question

Comment: People frequently downvote a question on meta if they think it's a bad idea.

Comment: thats crap.... :(

Comment: @Shahmir: Don't worry about it.  Meta is like "Whose Line is it Anyway?", everything is made up and the points don't matter. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KAGwNtI26w

Comment: @Bill: thanks for the video.. cheers me up :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just subscribe to each other's RSS feeds.  Go to any user's page and scroll to the bottom to find the RSS link.  This would allow you to have all of each other's posts conveniently grouped together in your RSS reader.

Comment: ooo nice, didnt know you can do that

Comment: lol can we have find user.. cause i cant find my buddys :D

Comment: @Shamir Javaid: type in google `username site:stackoverflow.com/users` http://www.google.com.ar/search?q=Shahmir+Javaid+site:stackoverflow.com/users

Comment: He he... That works :D