# Add Stack Overflow user as a favorite

Tags: support, users

Is it possible to add a Stack Overflow user as a fav?

Comment: ask on meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: meta.stackoverflow.com is the place to ask. i don't know there is a way, but i'd sure like one myself =)

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stackoverflow-would-be-nice

Comment: @SoftwareGeek A late try, but a try nonetheless: Unlike the others around here, I still think the usage for this is sound and well-founded, so I [created a browser addon for it](http://stackapps.com/questions/3535/stack-exchange-favorite-users).

Answer (score 3):

A friends' list or anything which will render this site in a social community is not what the owners of this site had in mind. In more than one of the Stack Overflow podcasts, Jeff mentions he won't do anything that resembles adding friends or something.

Comment: And unlike some other things Jeff says, this is something that most of Meta's regulars seem to agree with.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to a particular user's RSS feed. That's as close as I've found.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/1234567
```

Comment: Hmm, -2 for asking a question? Come on give me a break folks :)

@Carl Norum: Thanks but there ought to be a better way.

Comment: @Wisdom: Don't worry; since Meta is somewhat of a feature request tracker, question votes over here usually mean "I agree, this would be nice to have" or "I disagree, I don't want that feature".

Comment: thanks but -2 still on stackoverflow, sigh!

Comment: @Wisdom, The downvotes were probably because you asked a non programming question on a programming questions website