# Is it a possible for a feature to follow individuals in SO

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to follow a user automatically?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41483/is-it-possible-to-follow-a-user-automatically)

We have great individuals who are worth following in SO. Is it ever possible to implement the same so that we can track their noteworthy answers and questions.

Comment: Please avoid "following" individuals on Stack Overflow, instead concentrate on following content. This isn't a social network...

Answer (score 3):

There is [user feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/180970) to which you may subscribe. The link is displayed at the bottom right corner of every user page.

> User Feed:
>   Feed of the 30 latest questions, answers, and comments from this user