# Why is it not possible to follow someone?

Tags: feature-request

I'm sorry if this is not the right place to be asking this. Please move my question, if necessary.

I've been wondering: why is it not possible to follow people? I sometimes find certain people who answer questions of a particular type (usually tag that I follow) to be quite knowledgeable in that field. So... I go and check their answers to other questions they've replied to so I can sometimes learn cool new things. This often helps narrowing the learning curve when learning a new technology you're still a newbie in. So... wouldn't it be way cooler, if, (just like in GitHub), you could simply follow a person (both their questions and answers)...?

Comment: Because SO/SE is about content and not about people.

Comment: Also: [Is it possible to follow a user automatically?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41483/is-it-possible-to-follow-a-user-automatically)

Comment: It's 2013... The net is social. Doesn't this feature make sense?

Comment: what's the argument for it? "Because others are doing it" or "Because it's in"? Not having a "friendslist" sends a clear signal that SO is about content first and fore-most. Losing the focus on this would reduce the quality of SO.

Comment: RSS feeds are a different thing. While it may give you a stream of people's activity, you need a separate app/plugin/toolbar for that. Couldn't it be a bit simpler?

Comment: @carlspring think you meant to post this as comment on the answer from Oded?

Comment: I would argue it would ruin the quality of SO. I think it would make it cooler, as it would improve your learning through networking. It's a whole new level of learning, don't you think...?

Comment: You say "networking" I say "stalking" ;-) Also: as far as I know "cooler" is not one of the goals in SO/SE.

Comment: Oh, wow... downvote me, I'm an evil villain for asking a reasonable question...

Comment: Voting on Meta is different: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @JoachimSauer: "cooler" might not be one of the goals, but it is. And since there's always room for improvement, hence the suggestion. Nevermind.

Answer (score 9):

You can.

There is little `user feed` link at the bottom of each user page, giving you an RSS feed of their 30 last questions, answers and comments.