# keeping track of super-polite / impolite users

Tags: feature-request, users, voting, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A “Friends List” on StackOverflow would be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stackoverflow-would-be-nice)

It happened several times to me, that I gave an answer, that the asking user commented as very useful but is not even giving me an up-vote. Even after saying that an up-vote would be nice.
I'd like to keep track of those users. (i.e. [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398477/ashutosh), who got 28 answers on 17 question but has only 1 up-vote)

My idea: Mark users with the colors green, yellow or red, where green is for users I'd like to answer again, as they were very polite, while red is reserved for users, that really freaked me out, as they are never giving credit, where credit is due.
Users become "mark-able" as soon, as they can vote up.
Users can mark other users with a reputation of 100 or 200
The color will be show in the little box below their question (next to their accept rate).

Comment: I wouldn't call it friend list. more a hint to myself.

Comment: @viking It doesn't really matter if you intend to use it the same way, it's the same feature request (a way to mark certain users so that they show up differently from other users when you come across them)

Comment: a friend list, as described in the other post (...  allow us to be able to follow the Questions and Answers that are posted by ...), is very different. I am talking of a personalized for of the accept rate.

Comment: Just remember them.

Comment: I'd like to point out that there's a stackexchange API (I think) -- Something like this sounds like a project an individual user could build as a browser plugin.

Comment: @Neil I agree, it is to detailed for a standard feature in SO, bring on the SO personalised plugins

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't care for this idea, because it implies we should be answering the users and not the question. Let's respond to the content and not the writers.

Comment: Good point. on the other hand the writers should be encouraged to give credit, if an answer was useful for them.

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about individual users who you feel aren't contributing.  You also answered the question to help anyone else with the same problem, right?

Of course, if any particular user is annoying you in some way, at least enough that you remember them, you're free to not answer their questions in the future.  Is this just one user for you?  If so, that's not a problem.

With this particular user only having 75 rep, they're relatively new to the system.  [Some](http://twitter.com/jaredpar/status/17236008715) [users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) just rarely upvote.

Comment: It is not just one user, and eric is a bad example, as he also has no question :)

Comment: @Roger, exactly right, its about helping all users not just one.

Answer (score 1):

Some users don't care about rep, they just want an answer to their question. Which isn't that bad.

Remember that we are a Q&A site and rep is just the sugar on the cake (although sugar can be addictive).

To answer the question, I don't think we need to track the vote ratio. The prime focus is Q&A.

Comment: need. my. sugar.NOW!