# Is Stack Overflow a social networking site?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, social-networking

I know it's a Q&A site, but does it fall under the umbrella of social networking? There's a raging debate here at work, so I thought I'd put this question to the community.

Comment: I'd like to go on the record as thinking that this *isn't* a social networking site!!

Comment: If they're considering blocking social networking sites (pure speculation on my part, which tells you the kind of place that I currently work at) then I'd argue very strongly that SO is not a social network.

Comment: good point @Bill, fortunately they're not considering that. StackOverflow & the rest of the StackExchange sites are the few that aren't restricted by WebMarshal (or as it's otherwise known, WebNazi)

Comment: Social networking on a site frequented almost entirely by geeks? Seems counter-productive to me...

Comment: if you want counter-productive, you should go to reddit.com

Comment: @DaveDev: To your question: Look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103086/how-could-i-notify-stack-overflows-expert-users-about-my-new-question/103089#103089). That's why

Comment: @genesis-φ: thanks - makes sense. I'll modify the question to remove the edit (an enquiry into why this was getting attention today, almost a year after after it was posted)

Comment: BTW where did you spot that your question is "getting" more attention?

Comment: My notification bar at the top was lighting up any time someone answered a question or added a comment.

Comment: I don't have access to read this full *IEEE Software* article, but its public Abstract says [former] Stack Overflow CTO [David Fullerton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91687/david-fullerton) was interviewed on the topic of [Social Networking Meets Software Development](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260649476_Social_Networking_Meets_Software_Development_Perspectives_from_GitHub_MSDN_Stack_Exchange_and_TopCoder) - maybe someone with access may be interested to read it in full to see if David Fullerton weighed in with any explicit opinion.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_network):

> A social network is a social structure made up of individuals (or organizations) called "nodes," which are tied (connected) by one or more specific types of interdependency, such as friendship, kinship, common interest, financial exchange, dislike, sexual relationships, or relationships of beliefs, knowledge or prestige.

So I'd say no.  It would seem like *connections* between the nodes is the definitive feature of a social network and we don't have that.

Comment: Agreed. The only "connections" SO really has are tags, and those link questions, not people.

Comment: "a social structure made up of individuals [...] which are tied (connected) by [...] common interest..." Does that not describe SO?

Comment: @Purmou In that way, forums are also social media, as are many sites that have users and discussions. Actually, now that I think about it, are forums social media?

Comment: @Charlotte according to Wikipedia, yes:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_media#Definition_and_classification

Answer (score 54):

No, it is not. It's a Q&A site.

- We can't connect to friends.
- We don't have a means for private messages.
- We don't share pictures of our dog, kids, or house.

Comment: ... although sometimes we share pictures of ourselves in pyjamas ;)

Comment: Point, but luckily there isn't a badge for that ;-).

Comment: for newcomers: [the easteregg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140376/what-easter-eggs-have-you-placed-in-code/140507#140507) Jon referred to :)

Comment: I like this answer.

Comment: I should have just retweeted this answer.  It says basically the same as mine.

Comment: I like your comment, @Bill the Lizard.

Comment: I like the fact that Daniel likes our comments and answers. ;-).

Comment: *gamecat likes this*

Comment: I would just like to disavow any responsibility for, interest in, authority over or knowledge of Jon's post. Well, the "knowledge of" part ended 30 seconds ago, but the rest is still true.

Comment: @Pop: it was bound to happen :p

Comment: For how long have Web2 and social network meant posting private pictures?

Comment: the last 2 are doable on chat rooms though

Comment: [@caub, shush.](//en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Danger_Mouse_(TV_series)) You'll get chat filtered, and we can't do without chat.

Comment: Technically we do have DMs?

Answer (score 15):

I'd call it an *anti*-social networking site.

Comment: Only if you equate social to fun.  Or if you're on Math Overflow, I guess.

Comment: I would post a comment to this, if I didn't hate talking to people so much.

Comment: @gno: But you just posted a comment... or is it OK as long as the comment is hostile in nature?

Comment: Antisocial would be: maintaining links with people we don't like, posting compromising pictures of them and sending hate mail. You can call it Disgracebook, or flunkedOut.

Comment: Its not a social website period, and it doesn't actively fight against social network. Its purely a Q & A site.

Answer (score 11):

Stack Overflow forms a [social structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_structure), wherein we have patterns that define our relationship to the site and to each other.

While [social networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_network) almost always exist within every social structure, social structures need not formalize or recognize the networks that form within them. Stack Overflow is a good example of a social structure that does not recognize the social networks that are formed within its cultivated social structure.

Social networks come in a variety of forms, and for very broad definitions Stack Overflow comes close.  However, one of the defining characteristics common to nearly every social network is that people define specific interpersonal relationships within the social structure.

People are forming such relationships within Stack Overflow, but the site and software do not formalize these relationships.

I wouldn't say that Stack Overflow is a social network until the site and software themselves formally recognize those relationships.

In fact, far from supporting social networks, Stack Overflow has a few features that discourage social networks from forming within its social structure.  If you want to talk to a given individual, your only on-site option is a public comment on one of their posts.  While you and someone else may share in common your knowledge of Ruby, unless you encounter them off site you may never know that you also share the enjoyment of, say, painting. Chat fills the gap a little bit, but only for those that choose to participate.

Comment: I'm satisfy with this answer. Adam, can I ask you if you have good knowledge about sociology?

Comment: @Ooker No, while I'm interested in social systems that humans form, how they form, and how they can be guided, I have no particular expertise in them.

Comment: If you are interested in them, that's enough for me. I want to ask if I add [this feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139439/260800) on my own browser, will it makes SE become a social network site for only me?

Comment: @Ooker In some small way, yes.  It won't change how others use the site at all.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a social network due to the main ideological rule on which Stack stands - it is the value of question and value of answers you should care about. Nothing else really matters. Personalities just doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow does not provide a non-public means of user-exchange. Thus I guess you can apply a lot of pre-existing analysis of `twitter user exchange` to SO.

The public-only means of communication definitely helps the aspect of transparency a lot.

Answer (score -2):

The above answers give an academic, textbook-like (and dare I say, inconsequential) analysis to the question. I'd like to offer a practical perspective that business strategy planners (such as Facebook's CEO) should care a lot more about.

Anecdotally, I get my fill of bonding with other human beings via Stack Overflow to the point I am not as compelled to use Facebook to partake in this attention economy trade. Seeing one of those red balls in the Stack Overflow menu bar gives me the same acknowledgement of my existence by other beings, which the human evoloutionarily (?) craves, as those red alert sprites that Facebook's menu bar does.

This is significant from a competitor analysis point of view. **Stack Overflow is a substitute product for Facebook within a certain demographic**. So I would say yes it is a form of social networking.

[image]

Comment: This answer is off-topic.

Comment: There may be some "social networking" happening on Stack Overflow, but that does not make it a social networking site any more than Amazon is one. What makes a social networking site is the functionality and focus it has.

Comment: I think it is ontopic, but unclear.