# Allowing users to network

Tags: feature-request, support

SO is an excellent platform for techincal questions, ranging from newbies to . Would it be possible for SO to add a feature "Add as a friend" so that like minded people can also chat toget

Comment: Is this what you mean: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice

Comment: @Blogberd , you are right. Dont understand why I was downvoted. Thought this was for discussions, and I was not asking a stupid question either.

Comment: downvotes mean something different on Meta than they do on SO. Here, they mean "I disagree with your proposal".

Comment: You are not the first. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65261/is-stackoverflow-a-social-networking-site/65264#65264.

Comment: Get thee hence to facebook.

Answer (score 6):

You can chat right now. Just click "chat". Rooms can be topic based, site based, or whatever you want as long as they are broadly on-topic (related *in some way* to the site), and is reasonably behaved.

Comment: You are right. But for that users need to be online. I am looking for a networking model , through which user can connect to each other on SO.

Comment: @Sujay there have been discussions about that, always with the result that the vast majority of users (and, more importantly, the network's owners) are not interested in that kind of functionality. There is x number of existing sites that provide this should two SO users want to connect this way.

Comment: @Pekka Dont know how to accept your answer, so voted up your comment . BTW, can you please let me know how to Close a question.

Answer (score 2):

No, please no!

I can already see Jon drowning in friend and support requests.