# Is there any friend system on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow

As far as I know, Stack Overflow is positioned as a bit social networking service. So, is there a friends system here? Or at least a private messaging system?

Comment: 1. Well, no. 2. Nope. 3. And no (but there is a chat system).

Comment: StackOverflow is not a social networking site. Are you confusing that term with crowd sourcing?

Comment: [Is Stack Overflow a social networking site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65261/is-stack-overflow-a-social-networking-site)

Comment: The closest thing to "private message system" is chat - you can create yourself a chat room then invite someone via a comment. Many people won't agree though so don't expect immediate response. Note that when there are many comments between post author and one other member, the system creates such chat room all by itself.

Comment: Also see: [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> As far as I know, Stack Overflow is positioned as a bit social networking service.

....no, no we aren't.  If this happens, go ahead and send someone over to shoot me.

I kid, but no, social networking isn't what we're about, there are already sites for that.  We're about the *content*, not the *user*.

We're all for promoting the individual user, showing off their achievements and awesome answers and such, but not making them a target for tons of private messages which would end up as "hey, answer my question??"  Remember, everyone here is a volunteer.  Keep in mind that's one of several dozen "bad" scenarios introduced by things like a private messaging system.

Comment: Put me on the kill list as well.

Comment: I'm torn. On the one hand, everything Nick said. On the other, I'd like to follow my IRL friends.