# Allow users to include links to social media sites in profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, social-networking

It's been made clear in [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65265/154928) [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/914/154928) that Stack Overflow (and other Stack sites) are not social media sites. This fact, I agree with. I don't believe SO should ever change that. However, I believe we can supplement it more with current social media avenues.

For example, we already allow questions and answers to be shared on sites such as Facebook, Google+, and Twitter. Sharing on social media can be useful for content on the site to be found, shared, and collaborated on besides the usual methods of discovery.

I'd like to take that one step further and allow users to link to social media in their profiles easily, and optionally. Facebook, Twitter, Google+, GitHub, LinkedIn, Stack Careers, etc.

For example:
[image]

Personally, I would like to have a link back to my LinkedIn, Twitter, and GitHub pages to complete my professional profile here to make sure I'm discoverable outside of the site, if need be.

I do realize that the "About Me" section can be utilized for this function, but I believe it would be easier to use the simple iconic branding people are already familiar with instead of scouring the About Me section to determine if you shared any links to these sites.

Comment: Add careers in there as well..?

Comment: In the mean time, we could always place those social images in the about me section using `<img>` tags and make them clickable by wrapping them in anchor tags, or even markdown links...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Excellent idea.

Comment: I like it, but I'm going to guess this will be placed near the bottom of an already long priority list (if it's placed at all).

Comment: What's "Git", did you mean "GitHub"?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Or http://i.stack.imgur.com/ghp8g.jpg

Comment: This is a Stack Exchange/Social-Media-related proposal I'm not instantly opposed to!

Comment: One small but distinct advantage this proposal carries over recreating the same links in your "About me" as @Lix suggests: the `rel="me"` attribute on links, when used reciprocally between two pages, is used to tell Google that two profiles identify the same human person. It is not possible to add `rel="me"` to a link through any means on SO other than the one "Website" link in the profile (i.e., other uses are sanitized out), but these links could include `rel="me"`.

Comment: Hoping this is interpreted as objective and not judgmental :)  Your links to 'several' 'posts' are all to a Question asking if Stack Exchange is social **networking** - social networking is just 1 of [13 types of social *media*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_media#Definition_and_classification) - I'm not sure it can be claimed as fact that Stack Exchange is not some type of social **media** in general, based on that Question you linked to.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards https://stackoverflow.com/jobs now exists, if that's relevant to your "careers" comment.  You might know that by now (7 years later :), but figured worth posting this as your comment has gotten some upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if these features were added since this Question was last active, but *Edit profile and settings* [currently] has distinct fields for Github, Twitter (obviously I'm not on there [yet?]), and [just] 1 generic/catch-all field (that's where I put my LinkedIn):
[image]

(And FWIW, https://stackoverflow.com/jobs also [now] exists).