# Stack Exchange is not in the "List of virtual communities with more than 1 million users" (Wikipedia)

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, users, wikipedia

Apparently, the Stack Exchange community is **not** cited in the Wikipedia article ["List of virtual communities with more than 1 million users"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_virtual_communities_with_more_than_1_million_users).

Is there a special reason for that or should it be added?

I don't see any reason it should not. Just Stack Overflow has currently [about 5.6 millions users](https://stackexchange.com/sites#users) and the whole stack exchange community is even bigger. I'm not sure how to count the total number of different users over the whole network but it is certainly more than a million.

Comment: It also doesn't appear in the [List of virtual communities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_virtual_communities). At any rate, this might be a better question for [the article's talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:List_of_virtual_communities_with_more_than_1_million_users), where there is already an open question (from 2015) about whether Quora and gutefrage.net would qualify.

Comment: Actually it appears in the [List of Internet forums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_forums#S).

Comment: And yet, [SO is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/245360) :) @Surb

Comment: So maybe the Wikipedians make a subtle difference between the two. Or maybe no-one maintaining that list knows what they're talking about. Or there's an anti-SE bias on Wikipedia. But if I wanted to ask why x isn't listed on a specific Wikipedia page, Stack Exchange isn't the first place I'd ask that question, even if x happens to be Stack Exchange.

Comment: ajafi is right. This is something you need to ask the people at Wikpedia, not here.

Comment: I mean it *is* wikipedia.. you could add it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason it shouldn't be added. Stack Overflow itself, or the entire network can be edited in since is has certainly more than 1 million members. And it is indeed a virtual community... or not?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_community) it is not:

> A virtual community is a social network ...

And [SE is **not** a social network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65261/245360). You can debate about the wording in the *virtual network* article, but if you take the wording as-is, SE should not be on the list. However, I think reasonably seen SE could be on the list. If you feel like it, you can edit the Wikipedia page. Let the Wikipedia community decide how they feel about it.

Comment: If you go to the Wikipedia page linked to for social network, you can see that it is referring to the "theoretical concept as used in the social and behavioral sciences" and not social networking sites or platforms. The definition is is "A social network is a social structure made up of a set of social actors (such as individuals or organizations), sets of dyadic ties, and other social interactions between actors." I believe that does describe Stack Exchange.

Comment: Okay, I agree with that, but if you ask people here if they have to go on the list of "social networks" usually the answer is *no*. I however don't think we should read that strict.

Comment: That's probably true, until you define social network. If you provided the social science definition, I think most people would change their answer to "yes". It's clear that Stack Exchange isn't a social network in the sense of Facebook or LinkedIn, but it is a network of individuals who interact through social media (defined as " computer-mediated tools that allow people or companies to create, share, or exchange information, career interests, ideas, and pictures/videos in virtual communities and networks") potentially crossing...boundaries in order to pursue mutual interests or goals.

Comment: So, Stack Exchange is not in the list [List of social networking websites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_social_networking_websites#S). However in the link I gave I just see: "This is a list of active virtual communities with more than 1 million registered members. For a list of active social networking websites with more than 100 million, refer to this list."

Comment: (By the way, Wikipedia itself is not on the list... Strictly seen they are a community, but maybe not a social community)

Comment: Indeed. The wording is not uniform. @Surb

Comment: Unless and until a reliable third-party source reports on the user count for Stack Overflow and calls it a "Community", it will get edited out from Wikipedia as unsourced information.