# The Stack Exchange app is not a Social app (and not entirely Education either)

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app, social-networking

<sub>Disclaimer: I know all *development* on Stack Exchange apps [has been put on hold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/295232). However, these changes only require changing some settings in the Play Store Console and/or App Store Connect, not a new build of the apps.</sub>

While we all know Stack Exchange is [not a social network and/or a social media platform](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65261/295232), the Stack Exchange Android app is still listed under the 'Social' category in the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin):

[image: Play Store screenshot]

The iOS app has been categorized as 'Education' in the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8):

[image: App Store screenshot]

Since the [Stack Exchange mission](/tour) states that

> we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about [insert topic here]

a better category is ['Reference'](https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios-reference/id6006?mt=8) (['Books & Reference'](https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/BOOKS_AND_REFERENCE) in the Play Store).

Comment: I get the social media thing, and I agree that SE is not a forum, blah, blah... But why is *education* a bad category/fit? People ask questions about all sorts of things, and get to *learn* stuff.

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that an SE app would probably receive more exposure in the "social" category rather than "Reference". Marketing strategy?

Comment: Education is OK-ish (actually, I was originally going to ask to only change the Android app to Education) but not optimal.