# Follow a person?

Tags: feature-request, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A “Friends List” on StackOverflow would be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stackoverflow-would-be-nice)

I'd like to have feature like Twitter (I think; I don't use it) to follow a person and be updated on new posts by that person.

I do know that I can just click on that person's profile once every week or day, but I think an automated inbox-like feature would be better (it's like "subscribe" on youtube -- people could live without it, but it makes usage of the site more pleasant).

Comment: possible duplicate of [A "Friends List" on StackOverflow would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stackoverflow-would-be-nice) — one option that is mentioned is RSS feeds for users, which are available at the bottom of every profile.

Comment: I don't talk about making friend, I don't care at all about that person, but I would like to benefit from his knowledge.

Comment: @01 Then the RSS feed, a reader and a lot of patience is what you need.

Comment: @abel I can follow a person per RSS? Can you say how?

Comment: Goto the user profile page and look for the user feed link, it's near the bottom, for eg my feed is http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/150173 , add this to your google reader(or any other) subscriptions, then you will see updates the user makes in your reader.

Comment: Plus you should change your name to something which has 3 characters, if you want to be notified of comments addressed to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SE sites are not social network sites. They are content oriented, not user oriented. So following a person won't be that useful.

You can follow a question (by making it a favorite).

Comment: so why we have chat? I do know you can somehow explain it, but that doesn't make it right :P

Comment: I really dislike the attitude that because something is an A, it can't also be a B. And are you really telling me what I will or will not find useful? -1.

Comment: I disagree that it wouldn't be that useful. I list several specifically useful benefits of such a feature (that aren't provided by RSS feeds) here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice

Comment: if you follow a question, you'll get notifications?

Comment: I get no notifications for followed questions. I honestly don't even know why I bother; sure they're on a list on my page that I can access in like 5 clicks, but it's not like I'm going to follow all of them by visiting them every hour. I have tons!

Comment: Look: "The StackExchange sites ARE social network sites".

Comment: +1 Disagree. I found some person is "god like" and i will interest of any answer from them. But i don't like RSS.