# How do I follow a person using RSS?

Tags: support, feed

I know its possible - [Follow a person?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75195/follow-a-person#comment-182237) using RSS

How do I do it? I don't see any link in user profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/136179

Answer (score 3):

Check the page, it is there:

```
 <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed for user 01" href="/feeds/user/136179">
```

that's the 23rd line from the top of the document, linking to the relevant RSS feed. There's a normal link at the bottom of the page (like everything else on SO that has a RSS feed). [See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XurgJ.png).