# Follow/Fan feature

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, users, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A “friends list” on Stack Overflow would be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice)
>   [Follow a person?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75195/follow-a-person)

I like answers of some experience developers on stackoverflow is there any possibility of adding a follow / fans feature where I get notifications of answers to which guy I am following. I think most of the people love this feature and would be helpful for them to learn more stuff in short time.

Comment: Go to the user's page. Scroll to the bottom, look in the lower right corner and click on the "[user feed](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/22656)" link to subscribe to an RSS feed featuring that user's recent content. Do this for as many users as you find interesting and educational. Read and enjoy.

Comment: If you wanted to follow someone's answers, it's already there on their user feed, just plunk it into a feed reader and stalk

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow has always been about *answers,* not about *users.* Stack Overflow is not a social network, and it will resist efforts to make it into one.

If you want to follow a user, simply bookmark them, and check up on their recent activity occasionally.

Comment: You can have a follow feature without becoming a social network. I would like to follow certain people who I think are thought leaders in their field. I am interested in their ongoing contributions. RSS sucks. I would prefer a time-ordered aggregated view of followees' questions and answers. RSS doesn't give me this.