# Add Feature: Favorite Users

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A “Friends List” on StackOverflow would be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stackoverflow-would-be-nice)

I want to Favorite Users.  There are several users whose questions I always enjoy reading.  I would like to be able to Favorite them so I don't have to remember their usernames.

Comment: This request was already rejected here [A “Friends List” on StackOverflow would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stackoverflow-would-be-nice)

Comment: Facebook shmacebook.

Comment: It was NOT intended as a friends feature.  It was intended as a list of favorite authors, people who you feel have a consistently high quality of authorship.

Comment: [I-liked-this]

Comment: +1 it would really be nice to have this bookmark user feature to at least go to their questions and answers page.

Comment: This is NO duplicate : a favorite user function is distinct from a friend list. The motivation behind it is the quality of authorship as put by @diethbuddha. No need for the "favorite" list to be public.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to follow a user, you can bookmark their activity feed, go to their profile (by clicking on their name), and go to the activity tab, for example mine is:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver?tab=activity

If their user name changes, we'll redirect you!

But...we have no plans to make the site any more "social" than this with respect to following *users*, that isn't our focus.

Comment: Shame.  Sometimes you see a comment/answer from a user from months/years ago and have a question for them.  Don't want to update the question/comment with an unrelated question.

Comment: I understand the desire to stay away from the social aspect, however it is the higher quality of authorship of those users which makes me want to "follow" them.

Comment: Yes but what if we want to check on a large number of users ? The solution I found is to maintain a handwritten list of them to check on their activity. Quite painful compared to a "favorite" function (that should by the way be anonymous, no need to know how many people have favorited you). This way, there is NO social media aspect !