# Friends in Stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A “Friends List” on StackOverflow would be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stackoverflow-would-be-nice)

Does stackoverflow have a friend feature whereby I can mark certain individuals as friends?  I'd like to do this because there are certain people who I've come across who are credible and pretty much trust what they say.  Of course this list is big so I can't recall it off-hand.

Comment: And then maybe we could get some smileys up in here.

Answer (score 15):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/stack-overflow-meetups-april-6/

> We commonly say that Stack Overflow is run by the community. We also commonly say that Stack Overflow is not a social networking site. There’s no private messaging. **There’s no “friends” list.** The entire focus is on the knowledge shared

Probably not going to happen

Comment: This is too bad! Knowledge and social networking are interrelated. It could be a minimalist friends list and messaging feature. Not all comments to other users are of interest to the public.

Answer (score 0):

"Friend" is now a polluted meme thanks to Mr. Zuckerberg...I think this is maybe more of a request for a "trusted" badge one might apply to certain users who consistently provide great advice.

Or, in other words...one can upvote answers, why not the user who wrote the answer as well?

The badges/reputation are effective objective measures but do not leave room for subjectivity.

Comment: Why would you want that? We already have what's called "Reputation". Users with 10k rep on average probably put out quite good answers

Comment: It would be a possibility to follow answers of your real-life friends with same interests. I can imagine that as a useful features in philosophy.stackexchange.com