# Is there a way to add a user as favorite at StackOverFlow?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A “friends list” on Stack Overflow would be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice)

Sometimes, I found an expert and he/she has many great questions as well as answers, so I want to save it so that I can read it later. Unfortunately, I didn't find any option that let me do so. So I wonder Is this functionality available?

Thanks,

Comment: Add their profile page to your browsers favourites, or, star one of their questions / questions they've answered, so that it's on your SO favourites list... That should be enough to remind you who they are... I believe there's also an RSS feed for each user which you could add to your RSS reader of choice... But.. if they really are great, you'll come across them over and over again in your area of interest and you'll get to know their names anyway....

Comment: So why don't you "star a post as favorite" and then go back later and read the experts profile from there?

Comment: If this place becomes facebook I'm the f out.

Comment: @Chan A late try, but a try nonetheless: Unlike the others around here, I still think the usage for this is sound and well-founded, so I [created a browser addon for it](http://stackapps.com/questions/3535/stack-exchange-favorite-users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[No, there isn't.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice)