# How difficult would it be to add a "Favorite Users" tab in our profile?

Tags: feature-request, etiquette

There are certain users on SO that we may highly trust, that we know in real life, or that we are tutoring. And to prevent abuse of the feature, perhaps the number of "Favorite Users" can be limited to 5 or 10 or 20.

I realize someone else lobbied for this before, but I think my appeal is a little different - just put a hard-limit on the number of favorites, to prevent this turning into a certain other website.    Thank You SO !

Comment: See [A "friends list" on Stack Overflow would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/886/131713) and [all the questions that link to it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f886%2f*%22).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somewhere (I don't have a link at hand) it was stated, that SO isn't a social network for developers, so no friends, no groups, no wall, etc. I think I haven't missed these things so far (still, you can subscribe to user feeds, if you wish to *follow* someone or browse some else's activity, etc.).

Comment: Well we do already have aspects of "social network " - for example, if I click your link I learn about you (Hallo Germany)..  Well, alright. I see your gist. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Adel, hope everything is fine in New Orleans :)

Comment: And yeah, RSS feeds are available. I'll work it\

Comment: Hey thanks, yep New Orleans is just waiting for you to visit! We're back and even on StackOverflow ;)

Comment: `no friends` -- we're already developers, no need to rub it in...

Comment: LOL @ sarnold. But I swear I'm friends with you all here on SO and would gladly pick up a tab for yall.

Answer (score 2):

The benevolent creators of the Stack Exchange network (the SE family, if you will) have ever so thoughtfully already provided you this ability, you just need to follow these key steps:

1. Create a [SE Site] / Favorite Users folder in your browser of choice.
2. Add up to 1 billion SE users as bookmarks to this folder.
3. ???
4. Profit

Comment: You know, that's a great point ;) Thank You,

Comment: For some reason your advice sounds fatherly though, LOL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure out what the benefit of this feature would be.  Since SO users can't contact each other directly, what would you do with your list of favorite users?  Would you be following other users' questions?  Answers?  Comments??

The only use case that I can think of would be to 'favorite' users who are recognized SMEs or who work on projects/systems that you are also working on... but you'd find their questions/answers by doing a search anyway....