# Recommend a Friend to Stack Exchange (SE)

Tags: support, site-promotion

Is there a way that we can recommend a friend to one of the Stack Exchange (SE) sites? Like emailing them inside of SE?

Comment: If you want to recommend a site to them - send them an email/IM/SMS...  I don't think that this type of social "advertising" is SE's responsibility...

Comment: Why not just send an email yourself? What would emailing them from the SE site itself add?

Comment: Ok, great thank you.

Comment: Just thought of a more convenient way of doing it.

Comment: Also: repeat after me: the Stack Exchange is not a social network.

Comment: "The Stack Exchange is not a social network." - I understand that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [At least acknowledge cletus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice/914#914) =)

Comment: @Lix This type of thing happens for Area51.  There are even [badges](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/209/activist) for it.

Comment: @jadarnel27: You know, I actually came up with it independently? "Repeat after me" is perhaps a meme, and I honestly had not seen that post!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just making a joke, sir.

Comment: @jadarnel27: sorry, I think I missed a `:-P` there.. Hereby! :-P

Comment: As a user I'd probably mark such an email as spam.

Comment: The downvotes are unfortunate, since there's nothing to *disagree* with per se (it's not a feature request). But, the question is valid and deserves to stick around.

Comment: @Lix I think OP wanted something that would leave some trace in user statistics, possibly leading to badge, like in Area51

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can invite people into a private beta of a new site from the widget on the right sidebar, but we don't have anything like that for sites in public beta or that have graduated.

As others said, an email or an IM would be best in that case.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, personalized emails are more efficient at conveying a recommendation than some auto generated message like:

> "X would like to recommend to you site Y"

In my opinion, the best way would be to write the message yourself.

Comment: OK, understandable. Will do that then. by the way, what does IMO mean?

Comment: it stands for - In my opinion....

Comment: +1 for IMO, even i didnt know that :P

Comment: If I could +1 I would +1, but as I can't +1 I won't +1 ... But +1 anyways.

Comment: wat​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Sorry @MatthewRead, I didn't have enough rep points to +1 Lix's answer :)

Comment: @Kevdog777 I see :P

Comment: I can confidently attest that I have never clicked a link from an annoying autogenerated e-mail telling me my friend(s) is/are using X and I should sign up. Partly because I don't know that it came from them with their permission, and partly because I have a strongly negative knee-jerk reaction to e-mails not formatted as text/plain, but mainly because if they really found the service useful they wouldn't need to be corralled into telling me.