# Is there any easy way to follow an already existing user?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

Though there is RSS feed followup for an existing user in StackOverFlow, it will be very nice to have `follow` feature. Because creating RSS feed for every interesting user might become confusing when the list grows.

Comment: Hope my question is clear, my request for feature is to `follow` the user by means of stackoverflow's new enhancement. **Creating RSS feed for every interesting user might become confusing when the list grows.** Getting an alert inside stackexchange will be useful instead of opening the RSS feed.

Comment: [I think that should settle your request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/914/136489).