# Can we expect features from SE to find out our friends from Facebook using Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, social-networking

Is such a feature available? If not then can we expect it from SE?

See, LinkedIn has features that you give your Facebook email id and it will find out the friends from your Facebook accounts who have a profile on LinkedIn.

The same thing is available for Gmail and Yahoo! mail contact lists.

So can we have the same feature on Stack Overflow?

We would love to find out our Facebook friends and LinkedIn contacts on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Repeat after me: Stack Overflow is not a social network.

Comment: Downvotes on Meta indicate disagreement. Please read: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta - in particular the "Voting is different on meta." section.

Comment: I was quite shocked by this in Meta... until I noticed I could delete the post and recover my reputation... and even get a badge! xD

Answer (score 18):

No. There is no such feature and most of our users **do not want such a feature**.

Why?

Because we focus here on questions and answers, not social interactions.

Adding social interactions in such a way would only make for sites that have worse questions/answers.

See [A "friends list" on Stack Overflow would be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice)

Comment: You're on the right path for your 13th (!) Reversal badge!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Guess that giving the community answer to feature requests that have been discussed and rejected by the community will do that ;)

Comment: Also having (or knowing) friends on SE will increase the serial voting cases.

Comment: @hims056 - I can imagine the voting ring finder would have to work over-time if such a thing were ever to be implemented.

Comment: @Oded - And we will require more moderators' elections. :)