# Friendly URLs for Stack Exchange profiles

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Stack Overflow (and other Stack Exchange sites) include the userid in the public profile, giving public URLs similar to this:
https://stackexchange.com/users/2097759/rishi-dua

Unlike Stack Overflow Careers and many other websites providing a more user friendly URL like:

- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/rishirdua
- http://github.com/rishirdua
- http://twitter.com/rishirdua
- http://in.linkedin.com/rishirdua

Stack Overflow profiles have now become important for job applications, and people link to their profiles on their portfolios/homepage/visiting card. How about letting users choose public profiles with easy-to-remember URLs like https://stackexchange.com/users/rishirdua or http://users.stackexchange.com/rishirdua?

Is there a reason why Stack Overflow hasn't introduced public profiles without the uid?

Comment: No. User names are not unique, and should not become unique.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Why not make them unique just like fb, twitter, github, g+?

Comment: One reason, we are not those sites

Comment: Because Stack Exchange is not fb, twitter, github or g+. It's focused on the contents not the users.

Comment: The sites do have friendly URLs. `{Name}.stackexchange.com`. The profile pages don't. But peoples profiles are not important enough to need such 'vanity' URLs anyway.

Comment: @JonW well "peoples profiles are not important enough" that answers my question! Thanks. This was more useful than the downvotes. And yes, I meant profiles, not sites

Comment: The downvotes are not meant to be useful, just that people do not agree with what you suggest.

Comment: I was looking for a reason for the disagreement. JonW's comment and yours (after you edited it) gives a reason which is perfectly valid and I (somewhat) agree with that. Thanks

Comment: Numeric IDs are immutable, so an SE profile link will work as long as long as SE and the user exist. Links containing only the name will break if the user changes their name.

Comment: Yknow how incredibly annoying it is when you change your name on github and all your gist links die a violent, sudden death?  Yeah, that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, URLs shouldn't contain names.

Stack Exchange sites focus on content, not on users. Using userid in the profile makes more sense for a site which allows merging profiles, while allowing users to have fun experimenting with different names.

There [are users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259867) who [change their names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/244519) frequently, so the flexibility of changing names has use for a lot of users. If you want to link to your profile, use [your flairs](https://stackexchange.com/users/2097759/rishi-dua?tab=flair):

[image: profile for Rishi Dua on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

[image: profile for Rishi Dua at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

We shouldn't compare Stack Exchange with any other sites. Why?

> [Repeat after me: Stack Overflow is not a social networking site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/914/245167)

Comment: Thanks! That summed it up quite well